# How to push image to android emulator gallery using phonegap CLI

Tags: cordova

I have an image on my desktop that i want to push to my android emulator gallery using phonegap command line. If anyone can explain how to make this work using virtual sd card or any other way possible.

I tried `adb push <filepath> /sdcard/` and its always returns **Read-only file system.**

Answer (score 0):

After a deep dive into phonegap documentation did find the solution. In your phonegap command line follow below:

syntax:

`adb push abc.jpg /sdcard/0/`

PS: Posting this solution as can be useful to others. You need to findout the name of your sd card from emulator settings.